# Efficient numpy / lapack routine for product of inverse and sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, lapack

I have a matrix **B** that is square and dense, and a matrix **A** that is rectangular and sparse.

Is there a way to efficiently compute the product `B^-1 * A`?

So far, I use (in numpy)

```
tmp = B.inv()
return tmp * A
```

which, I believe, makes us of A's sparsity. I was thinking about using the sparse method 
`numpy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`, but this requires B, and not A, to be sparse.

Is there another way to speed things up?

Comment: This won't make any speed difference but why not just `return B.inv() * A`?

Comment: how about `trans(A)*trans(B^-1) = trans(C)`?

Comment: @Anycorn How would that speed up the computation?

Comment: Doesn't `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve` take a vector for the right hand side? So even if B and A's sparsity was swapped, it wouldn't help.

Comment: I think he meant that transposing them would allow you to use `spsolve`.

Comment: @agf But I can iterate over A's columns then

Comment: I can't imagine that would be faster, the way you're doing it now happens all in C rather than having to iterate over it in Python. Also, `spsolve` is actually in `scipy`, not `numpy`.

Comment: @agf, yes, that was my intent.

Comment: @Anycorn But this would still require to solve the same system, since the matrix I must invert is still B, now it's its transpose.

Comment: @Lag `trans(B^-1) = trans(B)^-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the matrix to be inverted is dense, `spsolve` is not the tool you want. In addition, it is bad numerical practice to calculate the inverse of a matrix and multiply it by another - you are much better off using [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), which is supported by scipy.

Another point is that unless you are using the matrix class (I think that the ndarray class is better, this is something of a question of taste), you need to use `dot` instead of the multiplication operator. And if you want to efficiently multiply a sparse matrix by a dense matrix, you need to use the `dot` method of the sparse matrix. Unfortunately this only works if the first matrix is sparse, so you need to use the trick which Anycorn suggested of taking the transpose to swap the order of operations.

Here is a lazy implementation which doesn't use the LU decomposition, but which should otherwise be efficient:

```
B_inv = scipy.linalg.inv(B)
C = (A.transpose().dot(B_inv.transpose())).transpose()
```

Doing it properly with the LU decomposition involves finding a way to efficiently multiply a triangular matrix by a sparse matrix, which currently eludes me.