# sparse matrix multiplication involving inverted matrix

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two large square sparse matrices, A & B, and need to compute the following: `A * B^-1` in the most efficient way. I have a feeling that the answer involves using `scipy.sparse`, but can't for the life of me figure it out.

After extensive searching, I have run across the following thread: [Efficient numpy / lapack routine for product of inverse and sparse matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766838/efficient-numpy-lapack-routine-for-product-of-inverse-and-sparse-matrix) but can't figure out what the most efficient way would be.

Someone suggested using LU decomposition which is built into the sparse module of scipy, but when I try and do LU on sample matrix is says the result is singular (although when I just do a * B^-1 i get an answer). I have also heard someone suggest using `linalg.spsolve()`, but i can't figure out how to implement this as it requires a vector as the second argument.

If it helps, once I have the solution s.t. `A * B^-1 = C`, i only need to know the value for one row of the matrix C. The matrices will be roughly 1000x1000 to 1500x1500.

Comment: How large are these matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually 1000x1000 matrices are not that large. You can compute the inverse of such a matrix using numpy.linalg.inv(B) in less than 1 second on a modern desktop computer.

But you can be much more efficient if you rewrite your problem taking into account the fact that you only need one row of C (this is actually very often the case).

Let us write d_i = [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0 ... 0 ], a vector with only one one on the i-th element.
You can write, if ^t denotes the transpose :

```
AB^-1 = C <=> A = CB <=> A^t = B^t C^t
```

For the i-th row :

```
A^t d_i = B^t C^t d_i <=> a_i = B^t c_i
```

So you have a linear inverse problem which can be solved using numpy.linalg.solve

```
ci = np.linalg.solve(B.T, a[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know how it goes. Also, I understand that it wouldn't take long to do the inversion, but I will have to do this process tens of thousands of times so I want to fine tune it as much as possible :)

Comment: I tried it out and after quite a bit of scratching my head i got it to work. Your solution works when using `numpy.linalg.solve()`, but I get an incorrect answer when using `sparse.linalg.spsolve`. My arrays where the following: `B.T = [[0.802, -0.396, 0.], [-0.594,  0.604, 0.], [-0.198, -0.198, 0.01]]` and `A.T: [[.25,.5,0.],[.75,.5,0.],[.0,.0,1.]]`; The correct answer for the 2nd row is `[2.00654938, 2.80114293, 95.19230769]`, but spsolve spits out `[.5, .5, .0]`

Comment: Ok. I assumed that spsolve worked the same as solve which is apparently not the case. But actually I am not so sure that from where you are now, using sparse matrices will gain you any speed-up. The main advantage would be memory consumption, but you are probably not limited by this, right ?

Comment: I will have to wait until later on in the implementation to determine if there is a speed up (and if it was memory bound). I finally ran across someone with a similar problem. It looks like spsolve has problems in a 64 bit windows environment (when using EPD+MKL), and just returns the second argument passed to it. But I tested it on the  Ubuntu version of EPD and it worked fine.